# GDAL rastercalc giving unexpected results

Tags: qgis, gdal, numpy

I have a raster file containing the following values:

- data values from 0 to 8488
- nodata values
- values equalling -3.40282347e+38

The values equalling -3.40282347e+38 are presumably supposed to be nodata values. I would like to generate a new raster where they are all equal to "nodata". For this I first tried to isolate them using the gdal raster calculator. I used the following expression containing functionality borrowed from numpy

`where(isnan(A), 1,0)`

I expect every value equalling nodata to become 1 in the new raster and every value not equalling nodata to become 0.

However what occurs is this:

- nodata values are converted to nodata
- -3.40282347e+38  values are converted to 0
- data values from 0 to 8488 are all converted to 9.

I'm bewildered as to why. What am I doing wrong here?